# Can "coincide" be use transitively?

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, neologisms

The New York Times today has an unusual use of "coincide":

> [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/08/health/covid-flu-twindemic.html?algo=combo_als_clicks_decay_96_50_ranks&block=5&campaign_id=142&emc=edit_fory_20220414&fellback=false&imp_id=459615681&instance_id=58527&nl=for-you&nlid=171320191&pool=pool/fa8f6616-7b25-42bd-bdbf-7abdec20107e&rank=3&regi_id=171320191&req_id=875922020&segment_id=89263&surface=for-you-email-rotating-health&user_id=1236141f50642a3bb9e92f57c2d869f8&variant=0_best_algo)
>
> *Looking at common-cold coronaviruses, some researchers have predicted that SARS-CoV-2 will become a seasonal winter infection that may well **coincide the flu***.

It is usual for *coincide* to be used intransitively, often followed by "with". Here is one example:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincide)
>
> coincide: intransitive verb
> 1a: to occupy the same place in space or time
> *The base of the triangle coincides with one side of the square.
>
> The heroic age of bridge construction coincided with the expansion of the railroads*

The NYT quotation is unusual but understandable. Are we therefore to assume a typo (omitting "with"), or does it represent a developing usage?

Comment: One can assume whatever one wishes, toyp or trend. But one data point is not a curve.

Comment: ... One swallow may sketch out a curve.

Comment: I've found 'These new rules have coincided the continued easing of lockdown that involves reopening shops. ' [[RX Live; July 2020; UK](https://rxlive.co.uk/i-need-wear-mask/)]. But decent analyses are based on thousands of data points hereabouts. And not all from medical concerns.

Comment: Life is easier when we give daily papers a pass on typos. No typos, and they'll never put a paper to bed.

Comment: You might compare "intersect" or "meet" which can be used both transitively and with "with". Of course, English is not very regular.

Answer (score 0):

This is, so far as I can tell, just a typo. [Ngram confirms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coincide+the%2Ccoincide+with+the&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) that "coincide the" is extremely rare compared to "coincide with the."